# Why is the Python Folder Sorter Script Giving me Errors and not Working?

Tags: python, sorting, terminal, runtime-error

So I have tried used both shutil.copy and os.remove and I keep getting error when this runs. Any suggestions? I am trying to get it to go through a folder "Downloads" and sort all the files by type into separate folders.

```
#!/bin/python

import os, shutil

path = raw_input("Enter your folder you would like sorted: ")

def searchFolder(path):

    if os.path.exists(path):
        dirList = os.listdir(path)

        for filename in dirList:
            if  filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".raw") or filename.endswith(".dng") or filename.endswith(".psd"):
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Photos"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Photos")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "Photos/" + filename)
            elif ".docx" in filename or ".doc" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Word Docs"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Word Docs")
                os.renames(path + filename, path + "Word Docs/" + filename)
            elif ".pptx" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Powerpoints"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Powerpoints")
                os.renames(path + filename, path + "Powerpoints/" + filename)
            elif ".zip" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Zip Files"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Zip Files")
                os.renames(path + filename, path + "Zip Files/" + filename)
            elif ".dmg" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Disk Images"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Disk Images")
                os.renames(path + filename, path + "Disk Images/" + filename)
            elif ".mp3" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Music"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Music")
                os.renames(path + filename, path + "Music/" + filename)
            elif ".pdf" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Pdf"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Pdf")
                os.renames(path + filename, path + "Pdf/" + filename)
            elif ".cpp" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "C++"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "C++")
                os.renames(path + filename, path + "C++/" + filename)
            elif ".psd" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Photoshop"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Photoshop")
                os.renames(path + filename, path + "Photoshop/" + filename)
            elif ".dng" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Photos/Raw Photos"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Photos/Raw Photos")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "Photos/Raw Photos/" + filename)
            elif not "." in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Folders"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Folders")
                os.renames(path + filename, path + "Folders/" + filename)
            else:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Other"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Other")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "Other/" + filename)

        print "Sorting Complete"
    else:
        print "Folder Does not exist"

searchFolder(path)
```

Comment: to begin with: `destination` is not defined. (in `shutil.copy(files,destination)`)

Comment: Sorry those lines were not meant to be there so I removed them. @ hiro protagonist

Answer (score 0):

Lines 7~9 are probably from some other cartoon. :-)

Here is your code pythonified, you'll probably spot mistakes more easily.

```
import os
def searchFolder(path):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        for ext, category in {('.jpg', '.raw'): 'Photos',
                              ('.doc', '.docx'): 'Word Docs',
                              '.pptx': 'Powerpoints',
                              '.zip': 'Zip Files',
                              '.dmg': 'Disk Images',
                              '.mp3': 'Music',
                              '.pdf': 'Pdf',
                              '.cpp': 'C++',
                              '.psd': 'Photoshop',
                              '.dng': 'Photos/Raw Photos'}.items():
            if filename.endswith(ext): break
        else: category = 'Other' if '.' in filename else 'Folders'
        os.renames(path + filename, path + category + '/' + filename)
searchFolder(input("Enter your folder you would like sorted: "))
```

Comment: @ veky will that crear bes directories if they don't exist? For example if there isn't a folder for photos will it make a folder for photos if it's not found? Also I thought you don't need brackets in Python?

Comment: Docs say it will: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.renames And, I don't know what you mean by "brackets" - I usually use the name for [], and I don't use them in the above code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant braces {}

Comment: You don't need them to delimit suites of statements, but you do need them for dictionary displays, like in {'.zip': 'Zip Files', '.cpp': 'C++'}.

Comment: why does it say that .endswith isn't a attrubute of the tuple? I thought the list was a dictionary not a tuple?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It should have been listdir instead of scandir.

Comment: Thanks!  That made a difference.